# Scala Log4j configuration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

So I'm trying to set up log4j in my scala code. This is what I have so far:

`LogHelper.scala`

```
package myPackage

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

trait LogHelper {
    val loggerName: String = this.getClass.getName
    lazy val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(loggerName)
}
```

`my class`

package myPackage

```
class MyClass extends LogHelper {

    ...
    logger.debug("my message")
    ...

}
```

But I don't really know where the logs go, or how to make it print to a file. My code is running a spark job which I run with spark-submit. How do I set this up to print to both the console and a log file?

Comment: Just to make everything clear, can you share please what dependencies do you have in build.sbt?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this post. They have precise steps to get logging in Scala.

**http://discuss.itversity.com/t/setting-up-log4j/5839**:

Step 1: Update build.sbt with below log4j dependency

`libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.14"`

step 2: create Log4j.properties file under src/main/resources and update as follows:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /tmp/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
SBT run, can be seen in /tmp/log4j/log.out log
```

Step 3: Can be used in code as follows:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

object HelloWorld {
  val logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    logger.info("Logger : Welcome to log4j")
  }
}
```

If you wanna know more about logging with log4j, I recommend this post on DZone:

https://dzone.com/articles/logging-with-log4j-in-java

Comment: Thanks for the update, will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the log4j.properties In your project there you will find the settings by which you can define where your logs should go. 
If these are coming on the console then you will find option of consoleAppender. I think this should work.